# Initiate click event automatically on a specified time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

how can i make a automatic click event on a time interval that I set

```
 <div class="nav">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" />
            <ul class="navright">
                <li><a class="navlink select ho" href="#">HOME</a>•</li>
                <li><a class="navlink ab" href="#">ABOUT US</a>•</li>           
                <li><a class="navlink pg" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>•</li>           
                <li><a class="navlink ps" href="#">SERVICES</a>•</li>           
                <li><a class="navlink cs" href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>          
            </ul>   
        </div>
```

and my jquery is this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myInterval = true;
     myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        } else {
            iScroll = iScroll + 200;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: iScroll
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Your code is working; on what element you want to click?

Comment: I want to click on all href during every 20 or 30 seconds

Comment: I really don't understand what are you looking for...

Comment: @A.Wolff I think the OP wants to change its code from a fixed scroll to a automatic click on the nav

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward ya, i was confused by all links getting same href attribute but if handler is bound to these links, then that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger programmatically a click on each element progressively using `eq` and execute the click using `trigger`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totDivs = $(".navright li").length;
    var currDiv = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (currDiv > totDivs) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return
        }
        $(".navright li").eq(currDiv).find('a').trigger("click");
        currDiv++;

    }, 2000);
});

$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Dysq6/